# How can I hide a column in a MUI X data grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I don't want to show the id field of my table. I use "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.6.1" version. Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';


const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 50},
    { field: 'testName', headerName: 'Test Name', width: 120,},
    { field: 'testDate', headerName: 'Test Date', width: 160 },
];

export default function DataTable(props) {

    const rows = [id:1, testName:"test", testDate:"23/03/2022"];

    return (
        <div id="resultTable" >
            <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={5}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}

            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Id column can be *hidden* or *display:none*. I tried to use

```
display: false
```

Or:

`hidden: true`

And I also tried:

`options: {display: false,  filter: false,}`, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Re *"it didn’t work"*: Can you be more specific? E.g., what happened?

Answer (score 26):

According to [MUI X documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#column-hide-property-deprecated), `hide: true` is now deprecated.

Instead you should use the [Column Visibility Model](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#controlled-visible-columns).

Example from the documentation:

```
<DataGrid
  initialState={{
    columns: {
      columnVisibilityModel: {
        // Hide columns status and traderName, the other columns will remain visible
        status: false,
        traderName: false,
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 22):

I found the solution.

```
{ field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 50, hide: true}
```

This is enough for me.

Comment: I like this solution a lot. If MUI is like other frameworks I have used, then this solution still allows me full use of the API on the hidden columns.

Comment: Hide is deprecated in v5 and will be removed in v6. See docs or answers from  Robinson or my self on this page.  https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#controlled-visible-columns

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [Robinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588166/how-can-i-hide-a-column-in-a-mui-x-data-grid/73383565#73383565) from the documentation, there's also a way to do this programmatically.  I used this code to hide some columns on the mobile version.

```
import React from 'react'
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";

export const MOBILE_COLUMNS = {
  id: true,
  value: true,
  value2: false,
  value3: false,
};
export const ALL_COLUMNS = {
  id: true,
  value: true,
  value2: true,
  value3: true,
};

const Component = ({rows,columns}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));

  const [columnVisible, setColumnVisible] = React.useState(ALL_COLUMNS);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newColumns = matches ? ALL_COLUMNS : MOBILE_COLUMNS;
    setColumnVisible(newColumns);
  }, [matches]);

  return (
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      columnVisibilityModel={columnVisible}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful with an explanation of where useTheme is coming from - without it being defined, the answer is incomplete and there are multiple instances of useTheme with react components.

Comment: @DylanGlockler - fair point.  It's an MUI method so I had assumed anyone looking at this answer would be familiar with it, but I could be wrong—updated answer. to include imports.

Answer (score 1):

The *GridColDef.hide* prop is deprecated, and you should use the column visibility to hide the unwanted columns: *[Data Grid - Column definition](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/columns/#controlled-visible-columns)*

Answer (score 1):

In the last MUI V5 you just need to pass object with exceptions values

```
  <DataGrid
    columnVisibilityModel={{
      id: false,
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to hide a field, but retrieve its value once I edit a row, which is also what OP commented on one of the answers.

The solution for this is adding the `editable` prop to the field like so:

```js
{field: 'id', hide: true, editable: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are column hiding filters in the column header cells or you can add GridToolbar to the data grid options which will give you a small toolbar above the grid for filtering, sorting, and hiding.

```
<DataGrid 
   slots={{toolbar: GridToolbar}} 
/>
```

columnVisibilityModel is a good solution if you don't want to let users manually select which columns they want to hide.
The caveat with using columnVisibilityModel is that you won't be able to use the build-in column hiding functionality in the data grid or with GridToolbar.

I've used columnVisibilityModel with media query to hide certain columns on mobile screens

Answer (score -1):

```
const matchesSm = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
```

const columns = [ { field: `${matchesSm ? false : "testName" }`, headerName: 'Test Name', width: 120,},...
]

Comment: The use of `useMediaQuery` is not explained in your answer and not related to the question. The `field` [property](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/) is of type `string` not `boolean`. See [GridBaseColDef](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/next/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/models/colDef/gridColDef.ts#L52-L55) in the GitHub repository.